# Button remains highight on showing MessageBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a button control which is bind to a command (using mvvmlight) which shows an alert if any validation fails. I have set a custom style for it, but when the alert appears the button remains highlighted. how to get rid of it?
The problem seems to be a focus bcz when the focus is on textbox, it works correctly.

This is the resource style

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNoSpacing" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource AppForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AppForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppChromeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" >
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. It will execute the `MessageBox.Show` method a little bit later, allowing the `VisualState` animation to finish.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your email-id");
    });
}
```